# notifyDatasetChanged() not update listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a spinner on actionbar and a listview in fragment. Spinner includes some folder structures, and when select some folder, it will update spinner data source and clear listview data by notifyDatasetChanged() in onItemSelected call back, then, it will call a runnable to load new data of folder and send a message to handler to update listview adapter by notifyDatasetChanged(). The issue is when handler receive message and update adapter, the listview not changed and will keep empty, getview() method is not invoked.

It seems the issue is occurred on 4.1.1, but not on 4.3.

Please give me some suggestions or a workaround to fix it since I need support 2.3 or higher.

e.g.

```
onItemSelected(){
    backward(folder);
}

backward(folder){
    notifyDatasetChanged() for spinner;

    clearListViewDataAndNotifyDatasetChanged();

    loadDataForFolderInRunnable();
}

loadDataForFolderInRunnable(){
    getDataFromHttp();

    sendMessageToHandler();
}

handler(){
    updateDataSourceForListView();

    notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

I found if I call notifyDatasetChanged() in onItemSelected() callback, then the listview cannot be refresh anymore.

A project member of android told me that this issue has been fixed. Does anyone knows how to fix it or some workaound?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68563

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the thread is not finished with loading the data and the listview is updated while the data is still loading.. for your handler try the following:

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it is not works for me. :)